# Creating subnets and classful addressing

Tags: networking, subnet

If classful addressing does not send subnet information and use predefined, fixed netmasks for each class how can we create subnets? If i'm right that we just set the netmask on a router (overwriting the default) and it use it for all incoming packets (in contrast to classless where the router takes the netmask send with the request)?

Comment: In classfull addressing you simply don't have subnets.

Comment: @hertitu Yes, You're right.

Comment: @Mulligan Ok, i got it.